# My Perl module is found but not being applied

Tags: linux, perl, module, cgi

I have created my own Perl module. I reference it from file Config.pm.

When I take the content from my Perl module and copy it into Config.pm, the script is triggered appropriately. But when I include it like this:

```
use severalnines;
Kernel::severalnines::config_severalnines($Self);
```

it is not triggered. I am sure that the file is found because when I try to change the name of the file, I get errors (Premature end of script headers: ).

This is the file (severalnines.pm) I want to include in Config.pm:

```
package Kernel::severalnines;

sub config_severalnines      
{                       
     $Self->{TicketAcl}->{'ACL-Name-Typer'} = {
        Properties => {Frontend => {Action => ['CustomerTicketMessage']},
             # current ticket match properties
             CustomerUser => {
                     Group_rw => [ 'Incident Management Severalnines', ],
             },
     },
     Possible => {
             Ticket => {
             Type => ['Incident',],},
     },
   };
}
1;
```

The severalnines.pm is located in /usr/lib/perl5/5.12.3 which is listed when doing perl -V.

What could the problem be?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Naming your module "Config" is a bad idea - such module already exists.

Comment: It's just part of the name, does it really matter?

Comment: package Config is bad, package Kernel::Config is ok.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your subroutine isn't doing anything with the parameter it is passed; instead it is setting a package variable `$Kernel::severalnines::Self`.

Add:

```
my ($Self) = @_;
```

at the top of your subroutine code.

Also, add:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

to the top of your module file (or perhaps after `package ...;`).  This would have alerted you that you were using an undeclared variable.

Comment: Thank you! Adding the my ($Self) = @_; worked. Don't understand why but I'm happy anyway. Adding strict and warnings didn't tell med that I had undeclared variables, I still got the same error message as I explained in my post.

Comment: Yes I did, could be that I updated the post at the same time you answered, so you probably couldn't see it. And now I understand why it didn't work regarding the parameter.